# Choose whether to show one component or another with ionic and angular framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, web-component, angular-components, blockly

I am developing an app with ionic and angular. In one specific page I added a component into the ion-content, however now I want to choose to display another one when I click a button. I have been looking for an option but it has been imposible for me to find how to do it. This is my actual code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="changeComponent()" color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="copy-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>    
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
 <app-blockly></app-blockly>
</ion-content>
```

What I want to do is to add in the ion-content another component called app-dual-blockly that has to be seen only when I click the changeComponent button and hide the actual app-blocky.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define your boolean properties to show components or not:

```
public showComponentA = false;
public showComponentB = false;
```

When clicking the button, toggle the action

```
changeComponent() {
    this.showComponentA = !this.showComponentA;
}

changeComponentB() {...}
```

In this case, you can easily work with ***NgIf**

```
<ion-content>
 <app-blockly *ngIf="showComponentA"></app-blockly>
 <another-component *ngIf="showComponentB"></another-component>
</ion-content>
```

If things grow, you can either choose a Angular Router or use a switchStatement.
For only two Components, this should do the trick.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for me perfectly like you said